# Update ListView Items

Tags: android, listview

I have a strange problem, I have a few different items in my ListView, which are enabled/disabled based on a preference. They show up in their enabled/disabled state correctly based on the preference, but if they were visible in the list when you open up the preference activity, they wont go to their correct state until they move off screen and back

I've tried calling getListView().refreshDrawableState() onResume of the main activity that the ListView is in, but it didn't seem to do anything.

```
@Override
public void onResume(){
    super.onResume();
    getListView().refreshDrawableState();
}
```

Comment: Post some code please...

Comment: Aha! @Cata - your suggestion led to getListView().invalidateViews() which works exactly like I wanted. Thank you.